# Results are displayed in different order in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React js.I would like to know what order it follows while displaying the results in console.
Expected output in console is:Before Function,Before Output function,After Function.
My console result is :Before Function,After Function,Before Output function.

```
import React from 'react';
import Output from './Output';
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log('Before function')}

      {/* { Component calling} */}

      <Output message='hello' /> 

      {console.log('After function')}

      </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Output component code:

import React from 'react';

function Output(props) {

    {console.log('Before Output function')}

    return (<h1>{props.message}</h1>);
    
}
export default Output;
```

Comment: Why is it a problem?

Comment: Thats the expected behavior, no problem here

Comment: I would like to know why it is displaying like that. Is there any order it follows while displaying it in console

Comment: Since it's just Javascript, and there is no recursive or any function call, the current render finishes, only then React (internally) calls render functions of other created elements. Try reading the JSX in-depth section in docs to understand what `<Output/>` means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code see the sequence of export statements. If you compile and run the code the first export statement is exporting App which will execute and print 'Before Function' and 'After Function' and then Output which will print 'Before Output function'.

Hope this answers your question.